# React Native Lottie Splash Screen

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs, lottie

I have some problems about with **Lottie**. I can't moving on this lib.
I have an animation with a **.json file ready** and I want to use it on the **splash screen.**
I don't know how to use it. More precisely, I couldn't find any documentation about the script I used.

Installed this:

```
npm i --save lottie-react-native
npm i --save lottie-ios@3.2.3
```

I also read expo's documentation about the loading screen, but I guess it wasn't very relevant. The way I used in other methods was different. As I am a new student, I chose Expo CLI. And I know I'm using Babel as a transpiler.

So I'm looking forward to your instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for animation launch screen using lottie in react native, i would suggest looking into this package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lottie-splash-screen

It implements animation splash screen using airbnb lottie files. Also, I apply this for multiple react native projects and it worked well.

You should check this in same question in stack overflow! ([React native iOS - splash screen using lottie file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434533/react-native-ios-splash-screen-using-lottie-file))

Answer (score 0):

Use the Image of first frame of animation as `Splash Screen`
Then start animation right after splash screen hide
and when animation stop, hide it as-well

Comment: I'm sure technically it will work, but I want to do it logically rather than in hard-coded.